# View all comments on post one click

Tags: wp-admin

In the admin site, on the page to edit or view a single post there is a meta box that shows the most recent ten comments on the post, with a "Show more comments" link at the bottom to load the next 10. You can load all comments by repeatedly clicking this link.

How can I modify this so that it will load all remaining comments in one go, without having to click again for every ten more?

Explainer video https://youtu.be/_9ybpw2qeTQ

The code is here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_comment_meta_box/

Comment: Please describe the problem here instead of linking to the video.

Comment: How to view all comments on post ONE click (without many clicks on link)